# Javascript async generators changing type of yielded value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator

So I have some generator method that gets data by calling another method, which returns paginated data. This generator iterates over the most recent buffer and `yield`s each item until there is no more fetchable data.

```
async function* paginated_generator(source, opts = {}) {
    buffer = await source(opts)
    while (true) {
        for (let item of buffer.items) {
            yield item
        }
        if (!buffer.paging.next) {
            break
        }
        buffer = await source({ ...opts, next: buffer.paging.next })
    }
}
```

The method that it is calling, in this case, looks like this, and constructs a new `Notification` instance for each piece of data.

```
async notifications_paginated(opts = {}) {
    let Notification = require('./Notification')
    let instance = this || opts.instance

    let data = await paginated_data(`${instance.api}/news/my`, {
        limit: opts.limit || instance.paginated_size,
        key: 'news',
        prev: opts.prev,
        next: opts.next,
        headers: instance.headers
    })

    data.items = data.items.map((item) => new Notification(item))
    return data

}
```

When I get the data from this method directly, or I insert something like `console.log(item.some_getter)` in the generator before it yields, I can see that the object is an instance of the `Notification` class. But If I `await` the next value from the generator method, the data that it yields has no access to any of the methods or getters attached to the `Notification` object.

What is changing when this data is returned from the generator?

Comment: Is `methods.paginated_data()` a reference to `paginated_generator()`? That's not really clear at the moment.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes. These are in different files, and the method is being imported.

Comment: Are you just missing the fact that it would have the style of `{  value: object, done: bool }`. For your generator, I think instead of using a for loop, you might as well return `yield* buffer.items`

Comment: @DieKaffir This doesn't make sense. A call to `paginated_generator(…)` returns an async generator instance, which can be (asynchronously) iterated but not `await`ed. It's not a promise that fulfills with a value containing an `.items` array property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the async generator correctly, but before we get to that, let's clean up the implementation slightly:

```
async function* paginated_generator(source, opts = {}) {
    let buffer = await source(opts)

    while (true) {
        yield * buffer.items

        if (!buffer.paging.next) return

        buffer = await source({ ...opts, next: buffer.paging.next })
    }
}
```

When you call an async generator function, it returns an async generator object, which implements both the async iterator and async iterable protocols.

There are a few differences between the syntax and protocols of asynchronous and synchronous counterparts for generator functions and iteration protocols:

- The `next()` method of the [async iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of#Iterating_over_async_generators) returns `Promise<{ value: T, done: boolean }>` while the [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol) just returns `{ value: T, done: boolean }`.
- Async iterables use the [`Symbol.asyncIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator) method instead of the [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) method.
- Async iterables can be consumed with [`for await...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) instead of [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Here's how your usage (probably) should look, based on the context you've provided:

```
const Notification = require('./Notification')

async* notifications_paginated (opts = {}) {
    const instance = this || opts.instance
    const gen = paginated_data(`${instance.api}/news/my`, {
        limit: opts.limit || instance.paginated_size,
        key: 'news',
        prev: opts.prev,
        next: opts.next,
        headers: instance.headers
    })

    for await (const item of gen) {
        yield new Notification(item)
    }
}
```

You can then consume your `notifications_paginated()` as an async iterable or async iterator of `Notification` objects.

If you were to attempt to buffer all the items in `notifications_paginated()` before returning, then your API might as well not use pagination at all since buffering the items defeats the purpose of paginating in the first place.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Though, is there a major difference between me using `let` and you changing that to `const` in this implementation?

Comment: I suppose I should have included that, but `notifications_paginated` does not return something that can be yielded itself. That data is from these methods https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/7fbe3e5d6b56469f99ba52459c38d915

Comment: @DieKaffir So `paginated_generator` is not the same as `paginated_data`, as you claimed before? And what does the `paginated_data` in your paste have to to with the `paginated_generator` async generator function from the OP?

Comment: oops, that was a mistake. I had misread your comment, and thought that you were referring to something else. `paginated_generator` and `paginated_data` are separate methods, that do different things.

Comment: @DieKaffir then your question does not actually contain the _usage_ of `paginated_generator()`? I don't see how the second snippet is relevant at all in that case.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts My question was asking "why does this data look strange when I call paginated_generator". Everything up to that point looked alright, though I was able to find what I needed using your comment. I was unaware of the `.value` field, and unaware of how async generators worked differently than regular generators (especially since I don't really use javascript!)